# Compute means of limited range of numeric variable grouped by factor levels

Tags: r, quantile

I have a dataframe with a numerical variable `V1` and a factor variable `Effect`:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rnorm(100)),
  Effect = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace = T)
)
```

For each `Effect` level I'd like to compute the means of those values of `V1` that fall between the first and the third quartile. I know how to compute the quartiles for all factor levels:

```
quants <- aggregate(V1 ~ Effect, data = df, quantile) 
quants
  Effect       V1.0%      V1.25%      V1.50%      V1.75%     V1.100%
1      A -2.30916888 -0.55815839 -0.02854676  0.55115731  1.53261063
2      B -1.96661716 -0.37066003  0.33178196  0.68864025  1.36860228
3      C -1.13813694 -0.42358228  0.01381897  0.92773709  2.16895597
4      D -1.02642090 -0.49385424 -0.22407620  0.72100821  2.18733299
```

But now I'm struggling with how to use the information in `quants`to compute the relevant means for all factor levels in one go.

**I've tried this so far:**

I've converted `quants`to make its columns more easily accessible:

```
quants <- as.data.frame.list(quants)
```

Then I've used this `tapply`statement:

```
tapply(df$V1, df$Effect, function(x)  mean(x[x >= quants_new$V1.25. & x <= quants_new$V1.75.]))
```

But the results are incorrect and there are warnings:

```
           A            B            C            D 
 0.172908276  0.167233413  0.002957323 -0.108590409 
Warning messages:
1: In x >= quants_new$V1.25. :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x <= quants_new$V1.75. :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x >= quants_new$V1.25. :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In x <= quants_new$V1.75. :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

How can the `tapply` statement be fixed to compute the means limited to the interquartile range for all factor levels? Other solutions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this within `aggregate` itself :

```
aggregate(V1~Effect, df, function(x) 
         mean(x[x >= quantile(x, 0.25) & x <= quantile(x, 0.75)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Using `dplyr` that could be :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Effect) %>%
  summarise(mean_val = mean(V1[between(V1, quantile(V1, 0.25), 
                              quantile(V1, 0.75))], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Two nice solutions, thanks. I'm just not sure whether the results are correct: while both the `aggregate`and the `dyplr` solution give identical results, which is reassuring, @rg22's solution, which seems okay too, gives different results. Now I don't really know whom to believe ...

Comment: You can test it yourself but I think rg255 solution doesn't take into consideration groups. You can get the same numbers by doing `df %>%
  filter(V1 > quantile(V1, 0.25) & V1 < quantile(V1, 0.75)) %>%
  group_by(Effect) %>%
  summarise(mean_val = mean(V1))` which removes `V1` values irrespective of groups.

Comment: Doesn't `keyby = Effect` in @rg255`s solution take groups into account?

Comment: Do you want to remove quantile values from each group or entire dataframe? My solution does it from each group whereas as far as I can tell rg255's solution removes it from entire dataframe.

Comment: BTW `tapply` can of course also be used: `tapply(df$V1, df$Effect, function(x)  mean(x[x >= quantile(x, 0.25) & x <= quantile(x, 0.75)]))` gives the same results as your two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've not checked whether the numbers are correct but this, using `data.table()` from the data.table package rather than a data.frame, should work for what I think you're after...

```
dt1[V1 > quantile(V1, 0.25) & V1 < quantile(V1, 0.75), 
  mean(V1), keyby = Effect]
```

This is grouping your data by "Effect", within those groups taking the values within the middle 50% of values, and taking the mean of those.

---

Edit, the above code took the subset first before grouping (sorry, my testing missed that) to take quantile of each group:

```
dt1[dcast(dt1[, .(unlist(lapply(.SD, quantile, c(0.25, 0.75))), qt = c("lo", "up")), by = Effect], ... ~ qt, value.var = "V1"), on = "Effect"][V1 >= lo & V1 <= up, mean(V1), keyby = Effect]
```

This provides the same values Ronak's answer. It's getting the quantile of each group, `dcast`ing it wider, joining that to the original data.table, then subsetting using new variables lo and up (the lower and upper quantile boundaries) and taking the mean per group of the remaining values.

Comment: Beat me to it. Elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: Looks fine. Just not sure whether the results are correct: `   Effect           V1
1:      A  0.130404987
2:      B  0.204476759
3:      C  0.002957323
4:      D -0.182221892` They're different than the results from @akrun's solution. Which solution gives the correct results?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann you're right - I've made an update that corrects that and repeats Ronaks values